# Alternative of Cascade Delete in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, cascading-deletes

I wanted to Delete all the records from all the table where there is reference of my primary table is present.

I know we have Cascade Delete option available where we can create/alter tables to assign cascade delete and perform this,

But I have a very complex data base with huge number of reference tables so I am looking for any alternative or other way I can achieve my target?

Comment: I would be that an alternative to cascade deletion would be more complex and error prone than what you currently have.

Comment: There is no automatic way... you have to build your own delete logic using relevant queries. Often inside a SP.

Comment: Number of referencing table is very huge and hard test the exact records deleted, But thank you for answering.

Comment: The larger the number of tables involved gets, the more it makes sense to rely on FK constraints that are defined as `on delete cascade`.

Comment: True a_horse_with_no_name and I have to delete them manually via SP using Dale Burrell's suggestion

Comment: If you really want to go overboard then you can find all SQL user tables from the master, get all of the FK's, then iterate this information to build up a delete tree such that, given any root record ID, you can dynamically create SQL to delete the correct records in the correct tables in the correct order from leaf  table to root table. I would go with Cascade Delete if you can

Comment: Yes using"SELECT RC.CONSTRAINT_NAME FK_Name
, KF.TABLE_SCHEMA FK_Schema
, KF.TABLE_NAME FK_Table
, KF.COLUMN_NAME FK_Column
, RC.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME PK_Name
, KP.TABLE_SCHEMA PK_Schema
, KP.TABLE_NAME PK_Table
, KP.COLUMN_NAME PK_Column
, RC.MATCH_OPTION MatchOption
, RC.UPDATE_RULE UpdateRule
, RC.DELETE_RULE DeleteRule
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS RC
JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE KF ON RC.CONSTRAINT_NAME = KF.CONSTRAINT_NAME
JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE KP ON RC.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME = KP.CONSTRAINT_NAME",got list of all FK reference